# Acessing external class property from Global.asax and Controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a timer in *Application_Start* (**Global.asax**) that interacts with a custom class (**Casa.cs**) property:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        Casa.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now; //ERROR
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000); // 1 minute
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Casa.SetLastUpdate);
    }
```

In the *ABOVE* example, `Casa.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;` returns exception right away (*'System.StackOverflowException'*). So if i comment it, it proceeds to the Controller, that tries to set `ViewBag.LastUpdate = Casa.LastUpdate;`, but this line of code generates exception (*'System.StackOverflowException'*) on `get { return LastUpdate; }` section of the **Casa.cs** class.

I (obviously) can't access from the View either.

The **Casa.cs** class:

```
public class Casa
{
    public static void SetLastUpdate(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public static DateTime LastUpdate
    {
        get { return LastUpdate; }
        set { LastUpdate = DateTime.Now; }
    }
}
```

So my question is, what is going wrong with the **Casa.cs** class, that i can't set the *LastUpdate* property in **Global.asax** and neither add it to the ViewBag in the Controller or access from the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your property setter you are trying to set the same property instead of for e.g.: class field. Setter invokes itself over and over again until stack overflow.
Also  `set { LastUpdate = DateTime.Now; }` does not seem right, maybe you ment `set { lastUpdate = value; }` ?

try something like:

```
     private static DateTime lastUpdate
     public static DateTime LastUpdate
        {
            get { return lastUpdate; }
            set { lastUpdate = DateTime.Now; }//or: = value
        }
```